# How to use dynamic data in the SCSS file of an Angular 2 app?

Tags: angular

I am making a hamburger as follows.

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="{
      backgroundColor: theme.majorTextColor
    }" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="{
      backgroundColor: theme.majorTextColor
    }" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="{
      backgroundColor: theme.majorTextColor
    }" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
</div>
```

I want each of the line to have a background color that I decide dynamically. So, I cannot add this directly to the SCSS file. But if I do the above, I am repeating myself. How do I do that in a DRY style without creating a separate component for the hamburger-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either define the style in your component.ts:

```
readonly hamburgerStyle = { backgroundColor: this.theme.majorTextColor };
```

and you can update your component:

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="hamburgerStyle" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="hamburgerStyle" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="hamburgerStyle" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
</div>
```

---

Or you can use a `ng-template` and use `ngTemplateOutlet` to insert it (or use both):

```
<div class="hamburger">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hamburgerLine"></ng-container>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hamburgerLine"></ng-container>
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="hamburgerLine"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #hamburgerLine>
  <div 
    [ngStyle]="{
      backgroundColor: theme.majorTextColor
    }" 
    class="hamburger-line"
  ></div>
</ng-template>
```